# passing dropdown value to action in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I am working on classic Asp, I want to send the value selected in drop down to another form through query string. I tried as below:

```html
<FORM method="POST" action="Includes/bfl_forms.asp?type=S&id="&rsStates("UID")>
```

and like this but didn't work out

```html
<FORM method="POST" action="Includes/bfl_forms.asp?type=S&id="&dest.options[dest.selectedIndex].value>
```

but the way I am populating drop down by as below :

```vbs
private sub generateStateDropDownList()`
    temp = ""`
    temp = temp + "<SELECT NAME=""dest"">"   `
    temp = temp + "<option value=""#"">Select a State"`
    rsStates.MoveFirst`
    Do While NOT rsStates.EOF`
        temp = temp + "</SELECT>"'`
```

I am unable to pass the drop down value to new form. Please assist me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have formatted your `form` tags incorrectly.  You should be doing something like this:

```html
<form method="post" action="includes/bgl_forms.asp?type=S&id=<%= rsStates("UID") %>">
```

or...

```html
<form method="post" action="includes/bgl_forms.asp?type=S&id=<%= Request.Form("dest") %>">
```

The code to populate your `select` tag, though, is a bit all over the place.  Firstly, it's more efficient to write your output directly to the buffer, like so:

```
Response.Write("<select....")
```

Rather than building up a string like that.

Secondly, you only need to supply the `option` list of the `select` tag, like so...

```vbs
<select id="dest" name="dest">
    <% BuildOptions rsStates(destId) %>
</select>
```

The `BuildOptions` function in the middle would be used to populate the options from your look-up list.

Speed is always of the essence with CLassic ASP. I recommend that you use something like [`GetRows`](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_rs_getrows.asp) of the ADO `RecordSet` object.

Answer (score 1):

How about using GET instead of POST?

```
<form method="GET" action="includes/bgl_forms.asp">
```

That will put all the inputs into the querystring,

Comment: The `GET` and `POST` methods both have their distinct advantages, but their usage should be [carefully considered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get).